# React Native upgrade error

Tags: android, npm, react-native

I got below error after upgrading my React Native version to 0.43.3

[image]

And when I tried to run **npm start** I got below error:

[image]

Are above errors somehow related? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Post this on react native facebook community too :)

Comment: yeah, I already done that https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13435

Comment: nope Facebook group :D 

https://www.facebook.com/groups/react.native.community/

Comment: @JokerFan Ohh... I never know that. Thanks for the suggestion.